# How to set Custom Page not Found in Blogger?

Tags: settings, blogger, custom-pages

I want to set my Bloggers Custom Page, Any one help me to set it. Please tell me the Script or code for this.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Blogger Dashboard > Select Blog > Select Settings tab > Search Preferences

Select edit option of Custom Page Not Found

Add the below script :

```
<h3>404 - Page was not found</h3> 

<p>It might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.<br/> 

Please check that the Web site address is spelled correctly.</p>

Go to our <a href="/">home page</a>
```

You can also add custom images similar to your blog theme.

See an example of a [custom 404 page](http://www.whatsappCity.com/404page)